Auditory Oddball (P300) paradigm using sounds of musical instruments
I am considering designing an experiment where participants are exposed to a series of sounds from various musical instruments, such as violin, piano, and flute. The task for the participants is to specifically identify the sound of a violin among these sounds. I am curious if this experimental setup could elicit a P300 response when the subject successfully identifies the violin sound. Could this be a valid approach to study the P300 wave elicitation in an auditory discrimination task?

Welcome. What do you think the answer is? Have you read anything so far on ERPs?
